# Estimation of the expected Euclidean distance between two random points on a unit $n$-hemisphere

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, geometry, computational-geometry

What is the best approach to estimate, with Wolfram Mathematica, the expected Euclidean distance (in a $(n+1)$-dimensional space) between two points selected uniformly at random on a unit $n$-***hemi****sphere*?

The approach I have in mind uses an expression whose length is proportional to $n$, while I would like a simpler and more elegant approach.

Comment: See [that paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.05692.pdf).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a normal distribution to generate $n$ values and `Normalize` to get a point on the sphere. Make sure that the last coordinate always has the same sign using `Abs`. Generate millions of these points and estimate the mean distance between pairs:

```
n = 3;
topt[p_] := MapAt[Abs, Normalize[p], -1]
points = topt /@ RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {1000000, n}];
distances = EuclideanDistance @@@ Partition[points, 2];
Histogram[distances]
Mean[distances]

(* 1.13137 *)
```

Comment: In the limit for large $n$ the mean distance and distribution converge to the same results as the $n$-sphere distances. In other words, in high dimensions a single coordinate doesn't make much difference to the distances. Also I suspect for both spherical and hemispherical cases, the mean converges to $\sqrt{2}$ for high $n$ but that's just a guess.

Comment: Based on Roman's closed form in the previous question: `Limit[2^(n - 1)*Gamma[n/2]^2/(Sqrt[\[Pi]]*Gamma[n - 1/2]), 
 n -> \[Infinity]]` is `Sqrt[2]`.

Comment: See [that paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.05692.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do the sampling (taking advantage of the built in `Sphere` function and `RandomPoint` functionality (modified from [a similar question on sampling from the surface of the sphere](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/235108/63709)

```
distanceDistributionOnHalfSphere[dimensionality_, nSamples_:10^5] :=
  With[{
   (* take a few extra samples account for loss *)
   randomPointsOnSurfaceOfNSphere = RandomPoint[Sphere[dimensionality], {4*nSamples, 2}], 
   
   (* define an operator that deletes points when either last coordinate is negative *)
   upperHemisphere = DeleteCases[{{___, x_}, {___, y_}} /; (Negative[x] || Negative[y])]
   },
  
  (* apply operator to the list and compute list of distances *)
  EuclideanDistance @@@ upperHemisphere @ randomPointsOnSurfaceOfNSphere
  ]

(* Evaluate mean of the sample *)
MeanAround /@ distanceDistributionOnHalfSphere /@ Range[10]
```

(The $N=3$ result is in agreement with @flinty's result*)

Comment: Really great! Thank you @JoshuaSchrier !